# What happens to product category after migration to enhanced e-commerce?

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce

After migrating from standard e-commerce to enhanced e-commerce, product category is no longer showing any results.

Answer (score 0):

For Enhanced Ecommerce, the product category will be under the dimension named `Product Category (Enhanced Ecommerce)`. **Please note**: *You need to ensure that Enhanced Ecommerce Reporting is enabled for that view.*

To check ..

```
View > Admin > Ecommerce Settings > 
Enable Enhanced Ecommerce Reporting
```

[image]